# NoneType occuring when I run my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

Why does this code return `None`?

```
 def html_list(inputs_list):
    print("<ul>")

    for html in inputs_list:
        html = ("<li>" + html + "</li>")
        print(html)

    print("</ul>")

bam = ['boom','bust']

print(html_list(bam))
```

Comment: What do you expect it should return and why?

Comment: This is what i'm trying resolve.Write the html_list function. The function takes one argument, a list of strings, and returns a single string which is an HTML list. For example, if the function should produce the following string when provided the list ['first string', 'second string'].

<ul>
<li>first string</li>
<li>second string</li>
</ul>
That is, the string's first line should be the opening tag <ul>. Following that is one line per element in the source list, surrounded by <li> and </li> tags. The final line of the string should be the closing tag </ul>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function has `print` calls within it, but does not **return** anything. If a function completes without returning, it really returns `None`.

This means that if you call the function inside a `print` statement, it will run, do the `prints` within the function, but return `None` which will then get passed into the `print()` function - so this is why you get the intended output and then a `"None"` at the end.

You can also see this through a more simple example:

```
>>> def f():
...     print("inside f")
... 
>>> print(f())
inside f
None
```